# mySQL or MSSQL best for auction site?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am writing an auction site that could be quite popular with 10's of thousands of items potential.. written in PHP / SQL

Would you say that mySQL would be the wrong way to go ?

I don't want the site to get so large that MySQL gets slow andthen have to rewrite it all on MSSQL ?

Thanks

Lee

Comment: MySQL will do the trick, combine it with memcached and you have a winner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An auction site would benefit from the strong transaction guarantees provided by either MS-SQL or PostgreSQL. MySQL can handle the workload but can not provide the consistency guarantees required of an auction application without pushing excessive conflict resolution code in to your application. At the end of the day, the most important thing is that your auction data is consistent during periods of high contention. Crude summary: PostgreSQL is faster and is the only open source database with the required level of transaction support.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/tutorial-transactions.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/transaction-iso.html

Answer (score 4):

If you want some examples, Facebook and Flickr use MySQL, so you should not worry about the engine, but your own code: learn about optimization, and prepare your infrastructure for replication when you will need it.

If you know PHP and MySQL, stick to that and invest energies in learning advanced concepts, rather than switching languages and platforms and starting anew, as both platforms have equal possibilities.

Check who is using MySQL here: http://www.mysql.com/customers/industry/?id=85

Comment: No way, Facebook seriously can't use mySQL ?

Comment: @Lee if you look at the link I provided, you will find facebook and some links to a few interesting articles about them and how they use it. There is also a facebook group by facebook employees about the topic...

Answer (score 1):

If you want an open source DB engine, consider using PostgreSQL rather than MySQL. It scales better and (since 9.0) has built-in replication features.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot to weigh up when considering which database to initially use for powering a new website, however I don't think 'umming' and 'arghing' over the apparent efficiencies of one database over another is one of the considerations at this stage. Let's be realistic here, all of the big DBMS players (MSSQL, mySQL, postgresql) have global brands that use their database for their websites. All of these databases are proven to work well in high traffic, high concurrency environments. But the true key to these databases working well in high demand situations is the way in which the database is structured and how the queries are written to extract information... this is ultimately down to you and how familiar you are with using the DBMS.

I would select your database based on these factors:

1. Cost - which is the most cost efficient
2. Limitations of your hosting environment - which databases are supported
3. Which DBMS you have the most exposure to - let's not over complicate the task, the key to all software development is KISS (Keep It Simple, Stupid!).

That said, the situation of having to change databases can arise and it is important to prepare for this eventuality by ensuring the conversion process requires minimal coding and headaches to you as the developer. You should write your PHP code in an MVC architecture so that your data access is separate from your object orientated PHP code. This way, if somewhere down the line you are required/forced to use a new DBMS, you can just create new data access objects to communicate with the new database.

So in short if you are familiar with PHP/mySQL coding there is no reason to alter this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but this is an opinion based question and can't be answered easily by the community.

However, while I'm here: I'd have to say MySQL for the moment.  In fact, [MariaDB](http://mariadb.org/).  MariaDB adds the Aria table engine and many new features / performance improvements over MySQL, and you use it exactly the same (it's a drop-in replacement.)  MSSQL is.. ehhh, I don't like paying for server software when I don't have to.  Not to mention PHP loves MySQL :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that either one will do fine, as long as you design and implement it properly.  Tens of thousands of items does not sound daunting to me.

MySQL will have the price advantage.  Do you already have a license for MS SQL Server?

Which one do you know better?